# Eliptic looking graph

Tags: vis.js, vis.js-network

What options should I use for making my graph looking like an Elipse ? I was messing with the `hierarchical` option under the `layout` module, but I've not gotten nowhere near my desired shape.

My graph is left to right, left node group connects to middle one, and middle one connects to the right one. It can be perceived as this image below.

Can someone point me in the right direction ? Thanks for your expertise

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the elliptic shape around the nodes and edges, you can either set a background image to your graph area or create a node of large size (but this way you may have troubles with node repulsion, though). Unfortunately, there's no way to make sure that all the nodes will always be inside the ellipse (unless you access the vis' canvas and deal with it on low level or do some other hackery).

Also AFAIK it is impossible to create those wavy edges, but for those rounded ones you may want to use `repulsion` physics instead of `barnesHut`. See also [physicsConfiguration example](http://visjs.org/examples/network/physics/physicsConfiguration.html).